# NullPointerException when analysing a Java project with SonarQube and when activating rules tracking quality issues in unit test source code

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I try to execute a SonarQube (Post build action) analysis after a Jenkins Job (maven clean install)

In my Jenkins job log I have this stack:

```
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) @ saga ---
[INFO] SonarQube version: 5.0
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/SAGA - Integration Continue - Sonar/target/sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.0
[INFO] [11:08:40.072] Load global referentials...
[INFO] [11:08:40.547] Load global referentials done: 482 ms
[INFO] [11:08:40.570] User cache: /home/jenkins/.sonar/cache
[INFO] [11:08:40.617] Install plugins
[INFO] [11:08:40.801] Install JDBC driver
[INFO] [11:08:40.813] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar
[INFO] [11:08:43.805] Initializing Hibernate
[INFO] [11:08:51.583] Load project referentials...
[INFO] [11:08:56.748] Load project referentials done: 5165 ms
[INFO] [11:08:56.751] Load project settings
[INFO] [11:08:58.344] Loading technical debt model...
[INFO] [11:08:58.429] Loading technical debt model done: 85 ms
[INFO] [11:08:58.468] Apply project exclusions
[INFO] [11:08:58.905] -------------  Scan saga
[INFO] [11:08:58.908] Load module settings
[INFO] [11:09:00.288] Loading rules...
[INFO] [11:09:00.877] Loading rules done: 589 ms
[INFO] [11:09:01.040] Configure Maven plugins
[INFO] [11:09:01.713] Compare to previous analysis (2015-05-09)
[INFO] [11:09:01.774] Compare over 30 days (2015-05-04, analysis of 2015-05-05 04:13:40.173)
[INFO] [11:09:01.780] No quality gate is configured.
[INFO] [11:09:02.133] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer...
[INFO] [11:09:02.143] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer done: 12 ms
[INFO] [11:09:02.144] Base dir: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/SAGA - Integration Continue - Sonar
[INFO] [11:09:02.144] Working dir: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/SAGA - Integration Continue - Sonar/target/sonar
[INFO] [11:09:02.149] Source paths: src/main/webapp, pom.xml, src/main/java
[INFO] [11:09:02.150] Test paths: src/test/java
[INFO] [11:09:02.151] Binary dirs: target/classes
[INFO] [11:09:02.151] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] [11:09:02.153] Index files
[INFO] [11:09:02.219] Excluded sources: 
[INFO] [11:09:02.222]   **Q*.java
[INFO] [11:09:04.555] 319 files indexed
[INFO] [11:09:06.639] Quality profile for java: Sonar way with Findbugs
[INFO] [11:09:06.971] Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 33.595 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-06-03T11:09:07+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/169M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project saga: null: MojoExecutionException: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project saga: null
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sonar.api.batch.rule.Checks.getField(Checks.java:180)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.rule.Checks.configureFields(Checks.java:167)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.rule.Checks.instantiate(Checks.java:152)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.rule.Checks.addAnnotatedChecks(Checks.java:127)
    at org.sonar.java.SonarComponents.registerTestCheckClasses(SonarComponents.java:128)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:82)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:122)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:222)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:223)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:65)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:52)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:128)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:171)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
SonarQube analysis completed: FAILURE
Build step 'SonarQube' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'SonarQube' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

**My Sonar plugins:**
 - Checkstyle 2.2
 - Cobertura 1.6.3
 - Findbugs 3.1
 - Java 3.3
 - PMD 2.3

If a delete the Sonar step in my Jenkins Job I don't have the problem and my Job is SUCCESS

I don't know if it is a Jenkins or a Sonar problem.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a similar issue, and it seems ([1](http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/JavaScript-Upgrade-to-version-2-4-gt-all-the-analyses-now-crash-with-a-NPE-td5034160.html),[2](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.sonar.general/42613)) this should be fixed by upgrading sonar to 4.5.4/5.0.1/5.1 as per http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6162.

Comment: Thank you, I updated to version 5.1.1 and it works fine!